# How to use bump2version to create a custom version tag

Tags: python, versioning, bump2version

We use bump2version to version our builds and releases in Gitlab, using a simple major.minor.patch (1.1.17) format.

Sometimes, however, it's useful to create versions outside the regular pipeline, with a custom version format, e.g. 1.1.17-test-1.

Trying bump2versions command line flags like this on a current version of 1.1.17:

```
bump2version.exe  --search 1.0.17 --replace 1.0.17-testing --verbose --new-version 1.0.17-test-1 part
```

Don't give any errors, but produces the wrong version-string in all files where the version-string is being managed.

The .bumpversion.cfg file looks like this:

```
[bumpversion]
current_version = 1.0.17

[bumpversion:file:CMakeLists.txt]
search = MVR_VERSION "{current_version}"
replace = MVR_VERSION "{new_version}"

[bumpversion:file:VERSION.txt]
search = {current_version}
replace = {new_version}

[bumpversion:file:installer/mvr.iss]
search = #define MyAppVersion "{current_version}"
replace = #define MyAppVersion "{new_version}"
```

In each file where the version-string is supposed to be changed, the change looks like this:

```
set(MVR_VERSION "MVR_VERSION "1.0.17"" )
```

which is not right. Proper search/replace would be

```
set(MVR_VERSION "1.0.17-test-1" )
```

Any hints on how to use bump2versions flags to achieve a custom version?

Answer (score 5):

As of `bump2version` v1.0.1, it won't produce the syntax error anymore.

You should do the following:

- Define a two separate `part`s for the 'test' and '1' parts of your version string.  Let's call them 'release' and 'build'.
- Configure the `build` part to have `values` and an `optional_value`.
- Add a custom `parse` so that both new parts can be parsed from a version string.
- Add multiple `serialize` options, so that a version number can exist *with* and *without* the two optional parts.

This is the config:

```
[bumpversion]
current_version = 1.0.17
parse = (?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)\.(?P<patch>\d+)(-(?P<release>.*)-(?P<build>\d+))?
serialize = 
    {major}.{minor}.{patch}-{release}-{build}
    {major}.{minor}.{patch}

[bumpversion:part:release]
first_value = regular
optional_value = regular
values = 
    alpha
    beta
    rc
    test
    regular

[bumpversion:part:build]

[bumpversion:file:CMakeLists.txt]
search = MVR_VERSION "{current_version}"
replace = MVR_VERSION "{new_version}"

[bumpversion:file:version.txt]

[bumpversion:file:define.txt]
search = #define MyAppVersion "{current_version}"
replace = #define MyAppVersion "{new_version}"
```

And this command succeeds:

```
bump2version.exe --verbose --new-version 1.0.17-test-1 bogus-part
```